# Symfony 3 Authentication/Login Form Not Working

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I am using symfony 3 to create an application that will be used to reserve lanes for a gun range. I have followed the symfony 3 documentation for getting a login and registration form setup and configured. My registration form is working, but my login form does not work. I just get "Invalid Credentials." returned to me no matter what.

**Below is my security YML.**

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    hide_user_not_found: false
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: our_db_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                username_parameter: _username
                password_parameter: _password
            logout: true
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/reservation, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**This is my login controller.**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Form\UserType;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {

        // loads security utilities
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        // renders route
        return $this->render('default/login.html.twig', [
            'year'      => date("Y"),
            'error'     => $error,
            'last_user' => $lastUsername,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
     */
    public function loginCheckAction()
    {
    }
}
```

**This is my repository so you can login with either email or username**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface; use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface; use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException; use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface {
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

        if (null === $user) {
            $message = sprintf(
                'Unable to find an active admin AppBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                $username
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message);
        }

        return $user;
    } }
```

**This is my user Entity**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max = 4096)
     */
    public $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
}
```

Not sure whats going on, but I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: How did you get the user into the database originally?  I suspect it has an improperly encoded password?

Comment: I used doctrine according to symfony's documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html

edit: accidentally submitted before linking.

Comment: Do you have proper field names in your login form?

Comment: Yup, _username and _password I followed the documentation to the T

Answer (score 2):

Quick overview said you forgot to add property field to you provider configuration. May be, the problem is not in that, but anyway:

```
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: username
```

I would also advice to encode password in entity's setter:

```
public function setPassword($password) {
    if ($password)
        $this->Password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    return $this;
}
```

And make sure your password in your database is really encoded. If you place unencoded password, you won't be able to use it. Just go to phpMyAdmin or any other tool and check. May be, you had an error during user creation.

Comment: I know they're encoded, and I'm using a custom repository implemented according to the docs. thats why the username property isnt there.